# Is the standard base of a vector space times a scalar factor also a base?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

There is an exercise where we shall give an example for a base of the matrix space M22 but it cannot be the standard base for matrix spaces.

My question is: Take the standard base (0,1) and (1,0) of a two dimensional vector space defined on real numbers. Would (a,0) and (0,a) where a is element of the real numbers excluding 0, also be considered a base? For me personally, it sounds quite stupid and also mathematically wrong but by looking at the definition of a base, I don't see any problem with it, since:

1. (a,0) and (0,a) show linear independence.
2. Any two dimensional vector can be calculated as a linear combination of those two vectors.
3. If the two vectors are grouped as a vector family excluding the standard base, the vector family (a,0) and (0, a) cannot be composited with a linear combination of the standard base.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: A basis is only required to be linearly independent and span the space. The standard basis has the additional property of being orthonormal, which this alternate basis only satisfies for $a = \pm 1$. Unfortunately, there are infinite dimensional vectors spaces that do not have orthonormal bases (or indeed, even the concepts of "orthogonal" or "norm"), so a more general definition of basis is required.

Comment: Not sure what your third point regarding “composited” is saying, but you’re correct that your first two points imply that $(a,0)$ and $(0,a)$ do indeed form a basis.  More generally, for the same reasons, any nonzero scaling  of any basis is indeed another basis.  It’s really not mathematically problematic in any way either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, for any finite-dimensional vector space, the answer is yes, as long as your scaling factor is not zero. It's provable by using the standard result that every change of basis corresponds to an invertible linear transformation, and multiplication by a scalar is one of the core linear transformations, but if we didn't want to do that then we can still prove it as follows:

Let $\mathbf{E} = \{\mathbf{e}_1, \mathbf{e}_2, \ldots, \mathbf{e}_n\}$ be any basis for the n-dimensional vector space $V$. Then we know that $V = \mathrm{span}(\mathbf{E})$ and the elements of $\mathbf{E}$ are linearly independent. Then let $\mathbf{E}' = \{a\mathbf{e}_1, \ldots, a\mathbf{e}_n\}$ be the elements of $\mathbf{E}$ scaled by non-zero factor $a$. So then:

1. For any $v \in V$, we can write $v = \alpha_1 \mathbf{e}_1 + \ldots + \alpha_n \mathbf{e}_n = \frac{\alpha_1}{a} a \mathbf{e}_1 + \ldots + \frac{\alpha_n}{a} a \mathbf{e}_n$ and hence $V = \mathrm{span}(\mathbf{E}')$.
2. If $\lambda_1 a \mathbf{e}_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n a \mathbf{e}_n = 0$, then $\lambda_1 \mathbf{e}_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n \mathbf{e}_n = 0$, implying that $\lambda_1 = \ldots = \lambda_n = 0$, and hence the elements of $\mathbf{E}'$ are linearly independent.

And hence $\mathbf{E}'$ is a basis of $V$.

You can even show that it works if you scale each vector separately (i.e. you have vectors $a_k \mathbf{e}_k$), but at that point you're halfway to proving that you can perform any invertible linear transformation on the basis to get another basis.

Comment: Any *invertible* linear transformation. :)

Comment: Good point, will fix :)